# Xcode Sqlite select next result

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I feel I am missing the obvious, the code below pulls back three results "201501, 201502 & 201503" I would like to put each result in its own `UITextfield`, I could have unto 52 results, can anyone help with the missing code, many thanks

```
_startWeekText.text = 201501
_endWeekText.text = 201503


- (void)allResults{

    const char *dbpath_rm1 = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statementrm1;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath_rm1, &dataTV) == SQLITE_OK) {NSLog(@"Select db opened");
        NSString *querySQLPrm1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:

        @"SELECT Wk_Num  FROM trendViewData WHERE (Name =\"%@\" ) AND (Wk_Num >= \"%@\" AND Wk_Num <= \"%@\") ",_resultSearchText.text,_startWeekText.text,_endWeekText.text];


        const char *query_stmtrm = [querySQLPrm1 UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataTV,
                               query_stmtrm, -1, &statementrm1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)

            while (sqlite3_step(statementrm1) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *rm1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statementrm1, 0)];
                _wk1.text = rm1;

                NSString *rm2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statementrm1, 0)];
                _wk2.text = rm2;

                NSString *rm3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statementrm1, 0)];
                _wk3.text = rm3;



            }

        sqlite3_finalize(statementrm1); }
    sqlite3_close(dataTV);NSLog(@"Select db Closed");


    NSLog(@"%@",_wk);
}
```

Comment: You have 52 text fields each with its own ivar? Yuck! Use an array of text fields to make this MUCH easier.

Comment: Extract the data into an NSMutableArray and display it with a UITableView.  *Don't* extract directly into text fields or you will drive yourself crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an array of your `UITextField` references, and then populate it on the basis of that:

```
NSArray *fields = @[_wk1, _wk2, _wk3];
NSInteger index = 0;

const char *dbpath_rm1 = [databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statementrm1;
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath_rm1, &dataTV) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Select db opened");

    const char *query_stmtrm = "SELECT Wk_Num  FROM trendViewData WHERE (Name = ?) AND (Wk_Num >= ? AND Wk_Num <= ?)";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataTV, query_stmtrm, -1, &statementrm1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        if (sqlite3_bind_text(statementrm1, 1, [_resultSearchText.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Bind 1 failed");
        }
        if (sqlite3_bind_text(statementrm1, 2, [_startWeekText.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Bind 2 failed");
        }
        if (sqlite3_bind_text(statementrm1, 3, [_endWeekText.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Bind 3 failed");
        }

        while (sqlite3_step(statementrm1) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            if (index < [fields count]) {
                UITextField *field = fields[index];
                NSString *rm = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statementrm1, 0)];
                field.text = rm;
                index++;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Got more results than I was expecting!");
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statementrm1);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(dataTV));
    }

    sqlite3_close(dataTV);NSLog(@"Select db Closed");
} else {
    NSLog(@"open failed");
}
```

Also, note, I log messages if any of the SQLite calls fail and I don't use `stringWithFormat` to build the SQL, but rather I use [`sqlite_bind_text`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for the quick response, I have copied the code into my app & got three errors upon paste     "if (index < [fields count]) {

Ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('char *(*)(const char *, int)' and 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long'))

UITextField *field = fields[index];

expression is invalid because subscript type 'char *(*)(const char *, int)' is not an integral or Objective-C pointer type

index++;

increment value of type 'char *(const char *, int)'"

Comment: @CoreyPowell Add the following line just before the `while` loop: `NSUInteger index = 0;`.